# [golang]Is it possible to write TLS server without certificate?

Tags: go, https, x509certificate, tls1.2

From client I already have tls config which sets `InsecureSkipVerify` to true. How to write server for this client which take any cert.
Can `tls.config` help in server too? like setting `InsecureSkipVerify` to true?

Comment: No, you can't have TLS without a certificate (and key).

Comment: you can create free totally valid TLS certs for your domain at https://letsencrypt.org ... reasonable priced domains can be created at https://domains.google.com/registrar   ... this might save you time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, as @JimB told you, TLS can't work without certificates.

The reasoning is simple: TLS is all about security, and certificates
are *cryptographic keys* which provide that security (TLS uses a so-called
"asymmetric cryptography" where each party has a key *pair* consisting of
a private and public parts; the public part is what get sent to another party
when doing a TLS handshake).

But on the other hand the security TLS provides is two-fold:

1. It provides mutual authentication of the parties participating in the
   exchange.
2. It provides encryption of the transmission channel¹.

Certificates are used for both aspects: the fact they contain cryptographic keys is used for (2), and the fact they have *owner's identity* encoded
in them (and verified by whoever was issued a particular cercificate)
is used for (1).

Let me not digress into discussing how (1) works in detail
(though I truly urge you to read some theory on it) but (1) is what
you actually want to sidestep.

The good (for you) thing is that it's cheaply doable:

- The TLS clients can be told to not verify the server's identity.
- The TLS servers can be told to do the same (and often it's the default
  mode they operate in—which is typical for regular websites
  for instance).
- You can create a so-called [self-signed certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate) for your TLS
  server.

The latter requires nothing but something which is able to generate
X.509 certificates; `OpenSSL` is typically used for this;
[just google for it](https://www.google.com/search?q=self-signed+ssl+certificate).

If you're on Debian or Debian derivative (like Ubuntu, Mint etc)
consider installing the `ssl-cert` package and using
the `make-ssl-cert` program it provides.

---

¹ To be precise, they only protect the very initial phase of the exchange during which the parties generate and send to each other keys used for symmetric encryption, which are then used to encrypt the communication channel, and are regenerated (and re-exchanged) periodically. This is done because symmetric algoritms are way faster.